# Delphi и Linux

Tags: delphi

Можно ли работать в Delphi на линуксе и создавать W приложения? У меня стоит убунта 11,04 надо на делфняке написать приложение для винды. Может есть у кого какие мысли как оболочку поставить?

Answer (score 4):

Lazarus+FreePascal

Comment: Да об этом уже читал. Интересно еще будут ли компоненты лезаруса выглядеть современно или квадратно. К тому же будет ли создание экзешника?

Comment: у лазаруса/фрипаскаля есть такой слоган - написано раз, компилируется везде. Как собрать с под линукса под винду - http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling_for_Win32_under_Linux/ru

Answer (score 3):

Глобально вариантов три:

1. виртуальная машина с Windows, в ней Delphi нативно. Из виртуалок рекомендую virtualbox (бесплатный), vmware (коммерческий) и parallels (особо хорош под mac).
2. запуск Delphi через эмулятор wine. [Статус поддержки см. здесь](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=42)
3. использование аналогичных Delphi сред. Например, [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/)

Всех упомянувших какой-либо вариант плюсанул. Все варианты пробовал самолично.

Могу от себя добавить, что никто не мешает при наличии windows-компьютера с доступом по сети, подключиться к нему по интерфейсу RDP и удаленно сидеть на нем. И писать программы в Delphi - какая им разница: запущены ли они локально или через remote desktop!?

Answer (score 2):

Где-то я читал, как умельцы ставили под вайном старые версии дельфов и вроде бы даже у них работало.

Comment: сам ставил в году так 2003. Почти с пол пинка 3 делфи завелась под редхатом.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Virtualbox спасет мир.
Вайн мир не спасет, но может слегка помочь.

Comment: Это слишком перебор ставить виртуалку на машну.

Comment: отнюдь. У меня стоит: Эдобовский Dream под виртуалкой работает быстрее, чем родной отпрыск эклипса. Такие дела. А винду поставить на комп не позволяет "политика безопасности фирмы". Ну и фиг с ними

Comment: У меня комм слабый чтоб тянуть две машины. Неужели никак нельзя писать для винды под линухой?

Comment: Писать можно, компилировать придётся всё равно в win.. Раз уж сидишь на линуксе, так и пиши под него..

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё одна малоизвестная кросплатформенная среда похожая на Delphi - MseIDE и MseGNU, но по ней очень мало русской литературы, работает она с компилятором Free Pascal. Информацию по установке можно найти на сайте http://freepascal.ru/. Я в ней пока ничего писать не пробовал. Embarcadero недавно объявила о выпуске новой среды Rad Studio XE 2, там можно писать под несколько платформ, но про Линукс вроде ничего не было сказано.